# How to wrap each 12 div in parent div in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How to wrap each 12 div in parent div in Asp.net MVC

```
@{
int picturesPerPage = 12;
int pictureCounter = 1;}


@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (pictureCounter % picturesPerPage == 1)
                    {
                        <text><div class="@(pictureCounter / picturesPerPage + 1)">
                        </text>
                    }
                    <div class="prfl_glry_box1">
                        <div class="prfl_glry_box_img">
                            <a href="@item.BigImageUrl" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                                <img src="@item.BigImageUrl">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    if (pictureCounter % picturesPerPage == 1)
                    {<text></div></text>}
                    pictureCounter++;
                }
```

I get this error of the last if statement

> Encountered end tag "text" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced

Comment: Why you need to use `<text>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding the unbalanced tags using Html.Raw

```
 @Html.Raw("<text></div></text>")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine :-

```
@{
int picturesPerPage = 12;
int pictureCounter = 1;}


      @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
           if (pictureCounter % picturesPerPage == 1)
             {
               <text><div class="@(pictureCounter / picturesPerPage + 1)"> // remove '</text>' from here  
             }
            <div class="prfl_glry_box1">
                <div class="prfl_glry_box_img">
                    <a href="@item.BigImageUrl" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
                            <img src="@item.BigImageUrl">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
           if (pictureCounter % picturesPerPage == 1)
            {</div></text>}     //remove '<text>' from here
             pictureCounter++;
        }
```

Comment: not good , because if you wrap all with <text> the code isn't work

Comment: I try it before, it make all the code as html content